# Apply band pass filter (BPF) before calculating the power of a signal (PSD)?

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, bandpass, power-spectral-density

From my understanding PSD tries to give a good estimation on the power each frequency attributes to the overall signal power.

If I am only interested in a frequency range $(\omega_0 \leq \omega \leq \omega_1)$, could I put the signal through a band pass filter for that same frequency range then calculate the signal power using this formula:

$$P_x = \frac{1}{N_1 - N_0 + 1}\sum_{n = N_0}^{n=N_1} \left|x(n)\right|^2  $$

Would this technique give me what I am looking for, (the power of the signal from $N_0$ to $N_1$ for the specific frequency range)?

How does this compare to PSD estimation using any of the popular techniques?

Pros, Cons?

Thank you!

Comment: i would say the answer is "yes, it should give you what you are looking for".  Pros: simple and consistent.  Cons: might be more expensive if $N_0 \ll N_1$ than an FFT.  your BPF will likely need to be sharp on both left and right.

Answer (score -1):

You can switch to the frequency domain with regards to [Parseval's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval's_theorem). I guess you can transform your problem via [discrete-time fourier transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Fourier_transform).